# Redirecting with a reverse proxy nginx

Tags: nginx

I have a reverse proxy nginx that listens on port 8888. The frontend is listening to 8000. The problem is the following: the browser is redirected to `http://frontend:8000/user/username`. At this stage, nginx is supposed to edit the replied `Location` HTTP header to redirect towards the same URL, but with an ending `/`.

A trivial rewrite redirect directive unfortunately changes the port to the nginx port, so I end up loading `http://frontend:8888/user/username/`. Adding `port_in_redirect off` does not solve, because the port is stripped and I end up to `http://frontend/user/username`

Currently I have (the nginx server is on a localhost docker container)

```
location = /user/username {
    proxy_redirect http://127.0.0.1:8888/user/username /user/username/;
}
```

but this one gives me a 404, because apparently it is not doing a redirection at all, and it's trying to serve me a file

```
2016/05/12 12:12:16 [error] 186#0: *1 open()     "/usr/share/nginx/html/user/username" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 10.0.42.1, server: , request: "GET /user/username HTTP/1.1", host: "172.17.5.168:8000"
```

Comment: You've set up a redirect, not a reverse proxy, which would use proxy_pass not proxy_redirect. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @tim the nginx is a reverse proxy, but for that url must do a redirect.

Comment: You need to read up on regular expression matching. The = sign, from memory, means you need an exact match for the location to match. You probably want ~ (again, from memory). I could be wrong but that might give you a clue.

Answer (score 0):

This reply is made assuming the rather unclear question is well-understood from my side...

You wish to make requests like the following:

```
 1. Request (frontend:8000/user/username): client -> reverse-proxy (8888) -> frontend (8000)
 2. Response (redirect to frontend:8000/user/username/) : client <- reverse-proxy (8888) <- frontend (8000)
 3. Request (frontend:8000/user/username/): client -> frontend (8000)
```

1. You did not specify a `proxy_pass` directive in the configuration snippet you shared. It is supposed here that this directive exists, because otherwise your question becomes nonsensical.
2. You specify not wishing the redirects being done to the reverse-proxy, but rather directly to the frontend. However, your [`proxy_redirect`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_redirect) configuration tells exactly the opposite. I suggest you read its documentation (again).
3. The log snippet you shared in the end seems to come from the frontend component, not the reverse-proxy one (`host: "172.17.5.168:8000`). However, if it were (because of docker container + misleading port-binding), it would lead towards the absence of a `proxy_pass` directive, cf. bullet #1.